# UITextField in UIControl

Tags: swift

I'm new to IOS and I'm trying to figure out How to Detect touch of textfield in uicontrol subclass? 
When I touch the textField nothing happens.

```
class PasswordField: UIControl {

    // Public API - these properties are used to fetch the final password and strength values

    private var textField: UITextField = UITextField()

    func setup() {

        isUserInteractionEnabled = true


        // Setup TextField
        addSubview(textField)
        textField.delegate = self
        textField.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        textField.backgroundColor = .brown

        textField.placeholder = "Password"
        textField.layer.borderWidth = 2.0
        textField.layer.borderColor = textFieldBorderColor.cgColor
        textField.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        textField.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setup()
    }

    override func beginTracking(_ touch: UITouch, with event: UIEvent?) -> Bool {
        super.beginTracking(touch, with: event)
        sendActions(for: [.editingDidBegin, .editingChanged])
        return true
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you subclass UITextField?

Answer (score 0):

I request you to read the Apple Documentation before posting something basic:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextfielddelegate/1619590-textfielddidbeginediting?language=objc

Tells the delegate that editing began in the specified text field.

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField;
```

> This method notifies the delegate that the specified text field just became the first responder. Use this method to update state information or perform other tasks. For example, you might use this method to show overlay views that are visible only while editing.

Implementation of this method by the delegate is optional.

Comment: It doesn't work, when I touch the textField nothing happens.

Comment: can you show the full code of implementation and what did you try..

Comment: Yes, https://github.com/Jkurbs/ios-sprint-challenge-password-textfield. Thank you!

Comment: why do u need UIControl instead of a UIView? Any reason why you made the PasswordField subclass for UIControl?